# How to get chathead at bottomRight of the screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place the chatHead at the bottom right of the screen, but when I change the position of chatHead by changing `Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.Right`. I loose my control on that. Its motion works opposite of it.

The following is the code which I'm using:

```
public class ChatHeadService extends Service {          
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private RelativeLayout chatheadView, removeView;
    private LinearLayout txtView, txt_linearlayout;
    private ImageView chatheadImg, removeImg;
    private TextView  txt1;
    private int x_init_cord, y_init_cord, x_init_margin, y_init_margin;
    private Point szWindow = new Point();
    private boolean isLeft = true;
    private String sMsg = "";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.onCreate()");

    }

    private void handleStart(){
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        chatheadView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.chathead, null);
        chatheadImg = (ImageView)chatheadView.findViewById(R.id.chathead_img);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(szWindow);
        } else {
            int w = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int h = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            szWindow.set(w, h);
        }

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;
        windowManager.addView(chatheadView, params);

        chatheadView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            long time_start = 0, time_end = 0;
            boolean isLongclick = false, inBounded = false;
            int remove_img_width = 0, remove_img_height = 0;

            Handler handler_longClick = new Handler();

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) chatheadView.getLayoutParams();

                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                int x_cord_Destination, y_cord_Destination;

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        x_init_cord = x_cord;
                        y_init_cord = y_cord;

                        x_init_margin = layoutParams.x;
                        y_init_margin = layoutParams.y;

                        if(txtView != null){
                            txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x_diff_move = x_cord - x_init_cord;
                        int y_diff_move = y_cord - y_init_cord;

                        x_cord_Destination = x_init_margin + x_diff_move;
                        y_cord_Destination = y_init_margin + y_diff_move;

                        if(isLongclick){
                            int x_bound_left = szWindow.x / 2 - (int)(remove_img_width * 1.5);
                            int x_bound_right = szWindow.x / 2 +  (int)(remove_img_width * 1.5);
                            int y_bound_top = szWindow.y - (int)(remove_img_height * 1.5);

                            if((x_cord >= x_bound_left && x_cord <= x_bound_right) && y_cord >= y_bound_top){
                                inBounded = true;

                                int x_cord_remove = (int) ((szWindow.x - (remove_img_height * 1.5)) / 2);
                                int y_cord_remove = (int) (szWindow.y - ((remove_img_width * 1.5) + getStatusBarHeight() ));


                                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, layoutParams);
                                break;
                            }else{
                                inBounded = false;
                                }

                        }


                        layoutParams.x = x_cord_Destination;
                        layoutParams.y = y_cord_Destination;

                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, layoutParams);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        isLongclick = false;

                        if(inBounded){
                            if(MyDialog.active){
                                MyDialog.myDialog.finish();
                            }

                            stopService(new Intent(ChatHeadService.this, ChatHeadService.class));
                            inBounded = false;
                            break;
                        }


                        int x_diff = x_cord - x_init_cord;
                        int y_diff = y_cord - y_init_cord;

                        if(Math.abs(x_diff) < 5 && Math.abs(y_diff) < 5){
                            time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            if((time_end - time_start) < 300){
                                chathead_click();
                            }
                        }


                        x_cord_Destination = x_init_margin + x_diff;
                        y_cord_Destination = y_init_margin + y_diff;

                        int x_start;
                        x_start = x_cord_Destination;


                        int BarHeight =  getStatusBarHeight();
                        if (y_cord_Destination < 0) {
                            y_cord_Destination = 0;
                        } else if (y_cord_Destination + (chatheadView.getHeight() + BarHeight) > szWindow.y) {
                            y_cord_Destination = szWindow.y - (chatheadView.getHeight() + BarHeight );
                        }
                        layoutParams.y = y_cord_Destination;

                        inBounded = false;
                        resetPosition(x_start);

                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "chatheadView.setOnTouchListener  -> event.getAction() : default");
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        txtView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.txt, null);
        txt1 = (TextView) txtView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt_linearlayout = (LinearLayout)txtView.findViewById(R.id.txt_linearlayout);


        WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsTxt = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        paramsTxt.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

        txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        windowManager.addView(txtView, paramsTxt);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(szWindow);
        } else {
            int w = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int h = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            szWindow.set(w, h);
        }

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) chatheadView.getLayoutParams();

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.onConfigurationChanged -> landscap");

            if(txtView != null){
                txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if(layoutParams.y + (chatheadView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight()) > szWindow.y){
                layoutParams.y = szWindow.y- (chatheadView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight());
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, layoutParams);
            }

            if(layoutParams.x != 0 && layoutParams.x < szWindow.x){
                resetPosition(szWindow.x);
            }

        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.onConfigurationChanged -> portrait");

            if(txtView != null){
                txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if(layoutParams.x > szWindow.x){
                resetPosition(szWindow.x);
            }

        }

    }

    private void resetPosition(int x_cord_now) {
        int w = chatheadView.getWidth();

        if(x_cord_now == 0 || x_cord_now == szWindow.x - w){

        } else if(x_cord_now + w / 2<= szWindow.x / 2){     
            isLeft = true;          
            moveToLeft(x_cord_now);           

        } else if(x_cord_now + w / 2 > szWindow.x / 2){         
            isLeft = false;         
            moveToRight(x_cord_now);

        }

    }
     private void moveToLeft(int x_cord_now){

            final int x = x_cord_now;
            new CountDownTimer(500, 5) {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) chatheadView.getLayoutParams();
                public void onTick(long t) {
                    long step = (500 - t)/5;
                    mParams.x = (int)(double)bounceValue(step,x);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, mParams);
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    mParams.x = 0;
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, mParams);
                }
            }.start();
     }
     private  void moveToRight(int x_cord_now){
            final int x = x_cord_now;
            new CountDownTimer(500, 5) {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) chatheadView.getLayoutParams();
                public void onTick(long t) {
                    long step = (500 - t)/5;
                    mParams.x = szWindow.x + (int)(double)bounceValue(step,x) - chatheadView.getWidth();                    
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, mParams);
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    mParams.x = szWindow.x - chatheadView.getWidth();
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatheadView, mParams);
                }
            }.start();
        }

     private double bounceValue(long step, long scale){
            double value = scale * java.lang.Math.exp(-0.055 * step) * java.lang.Math.cos(0.08 * step);
            return value;
        }

     private int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int statusBarHeight = (int) Math.ceil(25 * getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        return statusBarHeight;
    }

    private void chathead_click(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CLICKED CHATHEAD",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    /*  if(MyDialog.active){
            MyDialog.myDialog.finish();
        }else{
            Intent it = new Intent(this,MyDialog.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(it);
        }
        */
    }

    private void chathead_longclick(){
        Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "Into ChatHeadService.chathead_longclick() ");

    }

    private void showMsg(String sMsg){
        if(txtView != null && chatheadView != null ){
            Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.showMsg -> sMsg=" + sMsg);
            txt1.setText(sMsg);
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams param_chathead = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) chatheadView.getLayoutParams();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams param_txt = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) txtView.getLayoutParams();

            txt_linearlayout.getLayoutParams().height = chatheadView.getHeight();       
            txt_linearlayout.getLayoutParams().width = szWindow.x / 2;

            if(isLeft){                             
                param_txt.x = param_chathead.x + chatheadImg.getWidth();
                param_txt.y = param_chathead.y;

                txt_linearlayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            }else{              
                param_txt.x = param_chathead.x - szWindow.x / 2;
                param_txt.y = param_chathead.y;

                txt_linearlayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            }

            txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(txtView, param_txt);

            myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 4000);

        }               

    }

    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(txtView != null){
                txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.onStartCommand() -> startId=" + startId);

        if(intent != null){
            Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();

            if(bd != null)
                sMsg = bd.getString(Utils.EXTRA_MSG);

            if(sMsg != null && sMsg.length() > 0){
                if(startId == Service.START_STICKY){
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            showMsg(sMsg);
                        }
                    }, 300);

                }else{
                    showMsg(sMsg);
                }

            }

            }

            if(startId == Service.START_STICKY) {
                handleStart();
                return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            }else{
                return  Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();

        }


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "ChatHeadService.onBind()");
            return null;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You've presented us with a wall of code, which will be annoying for us to read and debug for you. Sure we do need your code, but really just the relevant sections, not all of it at once. Can you please instead tell us: what you've tried, what error messages you got when you tried it (or what you observed), what you tried next, any research you've done on the topic... ie show us that you've made a concerted effort to fix this yourself and we'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the gravity `Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP` and set `param.x = screenWidth - viewWidth; param.y = screenHeight - viewHeight`. Because the axis is relative to the gravity

Comment: On setting  Gravity.LEFT| Gravity.TOP this chathead work very smoothly,that i know. But I want the chat head should appear to user at Bottom Right .And to control this at bottom the calculations getting messed up here.

Comment: did u find any solutions for this